# Misunderstanding the need for group by cause in Query

Tags: sql, group-by

I don't think sample data is needed to understand this question. I'm writing a query to determine the business associated with each customer as follows:

```
select 
    customers.cust_id, 
    sum(OrderItems.Quantity * OrderItems.Item_Price) as total_business 
from
    Customers 
     left outer join 
    Orders on Customers.cust_id = orders.cust_id
     left outer join 
    OrderItems on orders.order_num = orderitems.order_num
-- group by Customers.cust_id -- why do I need this if I'm just trying to access the cust_id column?
order by total_business
```

I don't understand why I need to have the `group by` clause, if I'm just trying to access the `cust_id` column. I was under the impression I could access (`select`) any column that belongs to the new table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can't mix normal column select with aggregate functions like `sum()`.

Either only use aggregates or normal columns or group by the columns and use aggregates on the rest.

Example:

```
food table
------------
name   type
------------
tomato  vegetables
mango   fruits
kiwi    fruits
potato  vegetables
```

Now if you want the food names then use

```
select name from food
```

if you want the number of fruits then

```
select count(type) from food where type = 'fruits'
```

but if you want the number of food for every type then do

```
select type, count(*) from food group by type
```

Comment: +1 for the excellent explanation, but am now reconsidering because you just made me waste three minutes trying to figure out if potatoes are actually vegetables. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without the Group By, your result set will have one row for every order from every customer. You want one row for every customer, with the sum of the extended prices of all the orders for that customer.